# Is it Ok to use id(threading.current_thread()) as thread identifier in thread's whole life?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I need store data for a thread when it havn't been started. After the thread start, it read the data. So i need get the thread identifier before it started. Python's `threading.Thread.ident` and `threading.Thread.native_id` only have value when thread is alive.

Now i use `id(threading.Thread())` get thread identifier before it start, and use `id(threading.current_thread())` in thread. Is this OK or there are some better solution? 
Thanks.

Comment: As id() method returns unique identifier of an object,  it should work fine.

Comment: From the design perspective, if you want to change the way ids generated or add some prefix , you code needs changes at multiple places. Hence, better extend thread class and add method get_identifier() that returns you an id.

Comment: In case, you do not want to extend a class. Consider passing unique identifier as Name argument to thread and access it using thread.name whenever you need id.